# Conditionally skip subproject in multi-module Gradle build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Consider the following Gradle project structure:

```
- root
|- build.gradle
|- barProject
 |- build.gradle
|- fooProject
 |- build.gradle
```

where the root **build.gradle** configures its subprojects like so:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    //bunch of other stuff
}
```

Now when I call `gradlew build` on the root project it automatically configures both subprojects and then builds them - all well and good.

I also know that I can skip a specific task with various means (`onlyIf()`, `[taskName].enabled = false`, etc.) but when I utilize any of those on `build` Gradle still runs all the dependent tasks (`compileJava`, `processResources`, `classes`, etc.) until finally hitting `build` which it then skips.

My question is, is there *any way* to have Gradle stop and go to the next subproject right after the configuration phase?

EDIT:

To clarify; each subproject has a property called `skip` that is evaluated in the configuration phase.

Now when I call `gradlew build` on the root project I want Gradle to, ideally, check that property and if it's true then to **completely skip** the corresponding project.

```
Executing external task 'build'...

//check project.skip -> IF true -> skip project, go to :foo ELSE continue
:bar:compileJava
:bar:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:bar:classes
:bar:jar
:bar:startScripts
:bar:distTar
:bar:distZip
:bar:assemble
:bar:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:bar:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:bar:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:bar:test UP-TO-DATE
:bar:check UP-TO-DATE
:bar:build

//check project.skip -> IF true -> skip project, go to end ELSE continue
:foo:compileJava
:foo:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:foo:classes
:foo:jar
:foo:startScripts
:foo:distTar
:foo:distZip
:foo:assemble
:foo:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:foo:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:foo:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:foo:test UP-TO-DATE
:foo:check UP-TO-DATE
:foo:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I hope this makes more sense

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you only want to build the root project or one subproject? How should the condition look like?

Comment: @lu.koerfer I made an edit to clarify

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all: An easy solution would be calling exactly the task(s) you need. In simple Gradle builds, task names are unique. However, in multi-project builds, each project can have a task with a specific name. This is the reason why Gradle introduced task paths. Task paths combine the unique project paths with the intra-project unique task names: `:projectX:taskY`.

Using project paths, you can easily specify the project-specific task you want to execute: `:build` for the `build` task in the root project and `:<subproject>:build` for the `build` task in a subproject. If a task name, e.g. `build`, is provided for a multi-project build, Gradle will search through any project (root and subs) for a task with the specified name and execute them all. This explains the current behaviour.

The task names for execution are managed by a [`StartParameter`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html) object of the Gradle [`Settings`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html). These `Settings` can be modified in your `settings.gradle` file, where you also include subprojects:

```
include ':foo', ':bar'

startParameter.excludedTaskNames += ':foo:build'
```

This line excludes the `build` task of the `foo` subproject from the execution. You could add the subproject task path (even independent from the task name) to the excluded task names, if a specific condition is met. But, I did not find a way to access the `Settings` in your build file, so this solution can not be used during configuration phase. However, if your condition is solely based on project / system properties, they can be accessed from `settings.gradle`.

Another solution for the configuration phase came to my mind, but it's basically what you already mentioned, because it simply skips the tasks:

```
if (project.skip) {
    project.tasks.all { task -> task.enabled = false }
}
```

This way, all tasks from the project (not only the `build` task) will be skipped.

Please consider, that tasks can also be executed, because they create a dependency for another project. Even `gradle :bar:build` will execute the task `:foo:jar` and its task dependencies, if `foo` is a project dependency of `bar`. You can disable this behaviour with the Gradle command line options `-a` or `--no-rebuild` or the following entry in your `settings.gradle`:

```
startParameter.buildProjectDependencies = false
```